# take-while on clojure.string does not work

Tags: clojure

I'm wondering why clojure does not treat string as an array like in scala or haskell.

I want `take-while` function on string as in scala below

```
scala> "chich and chong".takeWhile(_ != ' ')
res1: String = chich
```

But [`take-while` in clojure](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/take-while) does not seem to work with string.

```
user=> (take-while #(not= % " ") "chich and chong")
(\c \h \i \c \h \space \a \n \d \space \c \h \o \n \g)
```

Just to make sure char/string equality works in clojure,

```
user=> (= " " " ")
true

user=> (not= 'A " ")
true
```

`take-while` does work with vector only.

```
user=> (take-while #(< % 0) [-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3])
(-3 -2 -1)
```

Tried converting string to vector as well, but returns the same as input.

```
user=> (vec "apple")
[\a \p \p \l \e]

user=> (take-while #(not= % "p") (vec "apple"))
(\a \p \p \l \e)
```

how can I use take-while with clojure.string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write character literal instead of string with space:

```
user=> (take-while #(not= % \space) "chich and chong")
=> (\c \h \i \c \h)
```

That is because:

- `" "` - is `java.lang.String`
- `\space` - is `java.lang.Character`

more info [\ - Character literal](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters#__code_code_character_literal)

Comment: I was thinking `'A` would take it as a char, but happens to be `\A`.

Comment: @prayagupd Right, `'A` is a symbol in Clojure.

To understand `take-while` on strings, note that `take-while` calls `seq` on its argument, which effectively coerces a string into a collection of characters to operate upon.

If you are interested in imitating Scala, producing the string "chich", then you would need to convert the resulting collection back to a string. One way is to use `(apply str (take-while #(not= % \space) "chich and chong"))`, or explore the functions in `clojure.string` namespace, with one solution being `(first (clojure.string/split "chich and chong" #" "))`

Comment: @MikeFikes I was using `(clojure.string/join "" [\C \h \i \c \h])` to get back the string. But `(apply str [\C \h \i \c \h])` seems more natural. I was just solving hackerrank questions using clojure and thought `takeWhile` would take be efficient than splitting by `\Space` because `split` has to go till the end and also need more space. Appreciate for your helpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out that your code would work in ClojuseScript, because the host platform (JavaScript) has no character type, so characters are represented as one-character strings. On the JVM though characters are there own type.